# How to import a page property to a data service with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to import the trackingId from tracking.page.ts to geolocation.service.ts in my Ionic App. Anyone an idea how to do that with Angular and TypeScript?

Below you can see an extract of the code.

**tracking.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { GeolocationService } from '../../app/geolocation.service';
import { UserService } from '../../app/user.service';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia/ngx';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracking',
  templateUrl: './tracking.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracking.page.scss'],
})
export class TrackingPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  markers = [];
  geoLocations: any;

  watchLocationUpdates: any;
  isWatching: boolean;
  interval: any;

  geoLatitude: number;
  geoLongitude: number;
  geoAccuracy: number;
  timeStamp: any;
  uId: string;
  trackingId: string; // This is the trackingId
...
```

**geolocation.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GeolocationService {

  databaseUrl = environment.firebase.databaseURL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient
              ) {

    console.log('Hello GeolocationService Provider');
    console.log('GeolocationService: ', this.databaseUrl);

  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service to save the `trackingid` inside it and then inject it inside the second page.

Trying to do this outside of services will run into problems with Zoning and change detection.

Answer (score 0):

Define `trackingid` in service file with observable subject like

```
 public trackingid: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(1);
```

And then set it inside service and fetch it also like below

```
 public getTrackingId(): boolean {
        return this.trackingid.value;
    }


 public setTrackingId(){
        return this.trackingid.next(2);
    }
```

Now from component you can do get and set to trackingId.